# Repeating "que" in long sentence

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, subordonnées, coordination

> I don't want to go tomorrow. The reasons are that I'm tired and it will probably rain.
>
> Je ne veux pas y aller demain. Les raisons sont que je suis fatigué et __il va probablement pleuvoir.

Do we need to add *qu'* in front of *il*? Similarly for the following sentence with *parce que*.

> Je ne veux pas y aller demain parce que je suis fatigué et __il va probablement pleuvoir.

Do we need to write *parce qu'il* or *qu'il*, or just *il* suffices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the **qu'**:

> Je ne veux pas y aller demain. Les raisons sont que je suis fatigué et qu'il va probablement pleuvoir.

But I would not be shocked if somebody said:

> Je ne veux pas y aller demain. Les raisons sont que je suis fatigué et il va probablement pleuvoir.

Maybe not entirely correct, but IMHO many people would say it.

For the second sentence, which by the way I prefer to "les raisons sont que..." which is not too natural and a bit heavy, there are a few possibilities:

> Je ne veux pas y aller demain parce que je suis fatigué et parce qu'il va probablement pleuvoir. - OK, a bit strange.
>
> Je ne veux pas y aller demain parce que je suis fatigué et qu'il va probablement pleuvoir. - best one.
>
> Je ne veux pas y aller demain parce que je suis fatigué et il va probablement pleuvoir. - OK, feels strange, maybe borderline incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First, "*les raisons sont que*" sounds weird, I wouldn't use that.

*Parce que* is fine, but you could also just say "*Je ne veux pas y aller demain. Je suis fatigué et il va probablement pleuvoir.*" (especially if you're tired). It's clear that what you're saying are your reasons.

That said, with *parce que*, I would repeat *que* :

> Je ne veux pas y aller demain parce que je suis fatigué et **qu'** il va probablement pleuvoir.